Are there any quirks of French dialogue that may make it obvious that someone is lying, but only to a native French speaker?
This is a very specific question.I don't even know if it is even possible to answer.
I have a French character in my story that speaks mostly English, but his dialogue is written with a French twang, with some entire words replaced with French counterparts.
Dialogue example so you can understand what I'm getting at: “Zee cake is so magnifique zat you eat it already? You come back for more, honh?”
I'm wondering if there are any quirks of the French language where someone would be telling a lie, that a native French speaker would be able to spot a mile away, but my non French speaking characters wouldn't grasp.

Psychological research shows that, on average, people cannot tell if other people are lying. They spot lies insignificantly better (60% correctly identified lies) than if they were guessing (50%).
None of the "signs" that are commonly considered to indicate lies (nervousness, looking away etc.) are a sign of lying. People can be nervous and tell the truth and people can lie and not be nervous.
Experienced investigators can identify lies better than the average person, but they use context clues and situation specific criteria (e.g. that a true testimony has a certain level of detail) and cannot spot lies when they are presented with a video of someone lying taken out of context.
This means that there are also no linguistic markers for lies. There are no signs in the language, neither in French or any other, that tell a listener or reader that the person is lying.
You may want to read the Wikipedia article on lie detection as an introduction, if you are interested in the science of it.

That said, here are some possibilities:

A native French speaker will often be able to tell whether a French accent in English is genuine or fake.
Someone familiar with a region or culture will know when a person is lying about or unfamiliar with its details.

